# C# regular expression in PHP?

Tags: php

I want my PHP program to extract all the URLs from a html file. When I was writing a C# program to extract all the URL in a html file, I used the following regular expression. Then add "http" part to the beginning to get a full URL list. Can you please tell me how can I use the regular expression that I used in the following code to work with PHP?

```
        List<string> links = new List<string>();
        Regex regEx;
        Match matches;

        regEx = new Regex("href=\"http\\s*(?:\"(?<1>[^\"]*)\"|(?<1>\\S+))\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        for (matches = regEx.Match(downloadString); matches.Success; matches = matches.NextMatch())
        {
            links.Add("http" + matches.Groups[1].ToString());
        } //Add all the URLs to a list and return the list

        return links;
```

**I would really appreciate it if you can show it to me with an example:**

---

@julian Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I modified the code a little and used it in the following way:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://mysmallwebpage.com/');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link)
{      
    $returnLink =  $link->getAttribute('href');
echo "<br />",$returnLink;
}
```

but the result doesn't show exact URL address. it output things like:

```
/nmsd-gallery/
/home/?currentPage=3
javascript:noop();
```

Can you please tell me if there is a way I can get just the URL address? such as:
`http://mysmallwebpage.com/`

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: You should read up on [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument); it's far more reliable than regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mhm this are internal links of the page .. in this case you have to filter the js-links (or other unwanted files like images or so) and add the HTTP_REFERER as prefix

...

```
foreach ($links as $link)
{      
    $returnLink =  $link->getAttribute('href');
    if (stripos($returnLink,"javascript")!=false) // or other unwanted calls
    {
        if (stripos($returnLink,"http://") ==false)
        {
            $retunLink = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].$returnLink
        }
    } 
echo "<br />++",$returnLink;
}
```

there are much more cases to check .. but i think this gives you an example
...

Comment: This is a nice example. but I think if you run this code, you will still get those unwanted `Links` as the `Justin k` described. `Justin k` will need to modify the code little more.

Comment: @julian Thank you so much for the help and explaining it to me in detail. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try extracting URL's with the DOM-Framework

```
    $html = file_get_contents($aktPage);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($links as $link)
    {      
            $returnLinks[] =  $link->getAttribute('href');
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I have re-post my question after trying your methord